# 1 of the 3 callback weakreferences goes to null in the asynctask (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, null, weak-references

**Intro to me and my application school project**

Hi,

iam pretty new with android and for some school project iam building an application where users can configure regions to recieve alerts from. The app need also make it posible to recieve alerts around the current location of the app user.

The app gets its info from a xml feed and sorts the data by the configured regions. The workflow is 1. to get the alerts which are in the configured regions. 2. When gps alerts are enabled the app need to get the location and when it is known it needs to do the first step again but this time the gps region is included. (i need to optimize this proces LATER)

(*questions bellow*)

---

**intro to my app and problem**

I'm using a asynctask in my application to download some xml feed. When the asynctask is ready i need to call 3 places for do something with the result.

1 class saves the result in the local database (alertmanager)
2 fragments (in a tabview) needs to show the results (1 in a map an one in a listview)

Now i use `weakreferences` for giving the call back "references" to the asynctask. in the `onPostExecute()` i use `theWeakReference.get().updateMethod(result);` for updating the class/fragments.

The alertmanager (the class who needs to recieve the updates) also calls a gps manager in the same method where it calls the asynctask to get the gps location. When i comment out (in my case with a if) the line what calls the gps manager the weak reference of the alertmanager will go to null in the asynctask between the constructor (all references are filled) and the doInBackground (the alertmanager reference is null, the other 2 still filled) which results in a crashing app.

When i dont comment out the if the app works fine.....

---

**Alertmanager information**

This is the method in the alertmanager who calls the async task. The references are filled on this place.

```
public void GetAlerts(List<WeakReference<e_Alerts>> callbackReferences, Context context) {
    //Update the alerts in the listview and mapview with the local alerts.
    List<Alert> localAlerts = internalDc.GetAllAlerts();
    try {
        for (WeakReference<e_Alerts> callback : callbackReferences) {
            callback.get().UpdateAlerts(localAlerts);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("AlertManager", e.getMessage());
    }

    //If connected to the internet then update the local db and the views
    if (isConnectingToInternet(context)) {
        WeakReference<e_Alerts> wr = new WeakReference<e_Alerts>(this);
        callbackReferences.add(wr);

        // Update the alerts where no location is needed for so the user has a quick result
        externalDc.getAlerts(callbackReferences, areaManager.GetActiveAreas(false));

        // If gps region is enabled then find the phones location and update the alerts
        if (areaManager.GetGpsArea().IsActive()) {
            new GpsManager(this.context, this, callbackReferences);
        }
    }
}
```

The GpsManager extends the LocationListener:

```
public class GpsManager extends Service implements LocationListener {
```

The listener is implemented by the Alertmanager

```
// This method is caled by the GPS Manager when the GPS location is changed
    @Override
    public void OnLocationChanged(Location location, List<WeakReference<e_Alerts>> references) {Area gpsArea = areaManager.GetGpsArea();
        gpsArea.SetLocation(location);
        areaManager.SaveArea(gpsArea);
        externalDc.getAlerts(references, areaManager.GetActiveAreas(true));
    }
```

---

**Asynctask information**

This are the asynctask methods:

Asynctask constructor:

*Here the list callbackReferences contains 3 weakrefrences and all of them are filled (2x fragment reference 1x alertmanager reference)*

```
public At_allAlerts(List<WeakReference<e_Alerts>> callbackReferences, List<Area> areas) {
    this.mCallbackReferences = callbackReferences;
    this.mAreas = areas;
}
```

doInBackground code:

*The XmlDownloader: Downloads an xml feed an parses the xml to objects with a library*

*The AlertConverter: converts the xml object to the object i use in my app*

*Both classes can work without the asynctask class and don't use the references.*

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... inputUrl) {
    Log.i("At_allAlerts", "Asynctask for downloading and parsing mAlerts is started");
    try {
        //Downloads the alert XMLs from the internet and parses it to xmlAlerts
        this.mAlerts = new XmlDownloader().DownloadAlerts(inputUrl);
        // Filters the mXml mAlerts so only the mAlerts where the enduser is interessed in will remain
        this.mAlerts = filterAlerts(this.mAlerts);
        // Converts the remaining xmlAlerts to Alerts;
        this.mResult = new AlertConverter().Convert(this.mAlerts);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("At_allAlerts",e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

The onPostExecute method:

*When the programm comes in this method the `this.references.get(2)` reference (alertmanager reference) = null, the other 2 references are still filed*

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String xml){
    for (WeakReference<e_Alerts> reference : activityWeakReferences)
    {
        reference.get().UpdateAlerts(this.result);
    }
}
```

filterAlerts Method:

```
private List<Item> filterAlerts(List<Item> alerts) {
    List<Item> filteredXmlAlerts = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Item alert : alerts)
    {
        Location alertLocation = new Location("");
        alertLocation.setLatitude(alert.getGeometries().get(0).getLocations().get(0).getLat());
        alertLocation.setLongitude(alert.getGeometries().get(0).getLocations().get(0).getLng());

        for(Area area : this.mAreas)
        {
            if (area.IsOrganization() && alert.getCountryCode().toLowerCase().equals(area.getOrganizationcode().toLowerCase())){
                filteredXmlAlerts.add(alert);
                break;
            }
            else if(!area.IsOrganization() && isAlertInRegion(alertLocation, area)) {
                filteredXmlAlerts.add(alert);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return filteredXmlAlerts;
}
```

---

**My Question(s)**

- I think Weakreference are the right way for giving references to asynctask is this correct or do i need to give it as an other object? (class or object or whatever?).
- Why goes my reference to null? and only one of the 3? and only when i dont use the gps location class? and how to solve this?
- I read something about the garbage collector what can be the cause of this problem, is this true and when yes how can i solve this?

It would be fine when the answere are simple to understand since android is pretty new for me.

Comment: The answer to question #2 is - "because of WeakReferences". The answer to #3 is - "nothing much, the GC will reclaim anything you're not using anymore (unreachable objects)"

Comment: Thanks for your answere but this are not complete answers of question 2 and 3 becouse i need to know how to solve this problem. And i use the references right? i use them for the callback in my opinion?

Comment: Why is there a `List<Reference<e_Alerts>>` and what is `Reference<e_Alerts> wr = new Reference<>();`?  P.s. to work with weak references you have to check whether they are null or not because that's a thing you expect. Otherwise don't use them.

Comment: Sorry, the reference was for a test, i copied the wrong code, in my project it is a WeakReference again. i will update my question. - Ok i understand that i can check if they are null but when they are null spontaneously i'am never sure that the callback happened to the alert manager class. Since this is important i need a 100% sure working method, how can i provide this? (without memory leaks or something)

Comment: Dude, you can never have a guarantee that a WeakReference won't be reclaimed by the GC. It can go away any time. Thats what makes them good.

Comment: Ok, i understand that (now) but is there another (allways working) solution becouse i need the result in the alertmanager ALLWAYS? So maybe there is another (also good/best practice) way to give the callback references to the asynctask instead of weakreferences?

Comment: Just store a list of `e_Alert` objects directly rather than weak references to them. Only use weak references if you want the garbage collector to be able reclaim them. This may mean you need to implement some kind of function to deregister alerts, and remove them from the list, but only if that's functionality you need.

Comment: OK, i understand what you mean but don't i get memory leaks when i store  complete objects  (from e_alert type) in a list only for the callbacks?